# Problem with PostGis Shapefile Import/Export Manager with no explanation

Tags: postgis, shapefile, pgadmin-4

I am trying to import a shapefile into PgAdmin4.
I do it with PostGis Shapefile Import/Export Manager.
I have a « connection failed » message with no explanation so I do no know where to search …
[image: PostGis Shapefile Import/Export Manager message]
My datatable does not seem to have encoding problem anymore, my path neither ..
And I can open the shapefile in arcgis/qgis.
[image: shapefile table]

Does someone has a suggestion ?

**UPDATE**
I set the correct SRID, still not working.[image: PostGis Shapefile Import/Export Manager message with correct SRID]

Comment: did you tried to define the SRID?

Comment: What happens when you open the connection detail and click ok? (it should attempt to connect to the DB)

Comment: @JGH I succeeded in connecting to the DB, which is empty. But then I can't import the shp

Comment: @User2009 Indeed srid=0,  my SRID is defined for mon shapefile but not while importing. In the tutorials I red, thez said to define it after importing the shapefile

Comment: @User2009 my Postgis database is in UTF8 and my shapefile too, according to my cpg file

Comment: @J.Delannoy SRID can be define by uploading .prj in this [link](http://prj2epsg.org/search) and it will give you the number (SRID)

Comment: @User2009, thank you, My SRID is 2154. I set it , still not working

Comment: @J.Delannoy you don't need any SRID for the database, this SRID (2154) just for importing your shape file

Comment: @User2009 Yes I understood that few minutes layer, sorry. I updated my post, still not working

Comment: Try from the Options button, click on (Loading data using copy, create spatial automatically)

Comment: both are already checked

Comment: oh, that's strange. Anyway you can use  (shp2pgsql) from this [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/41802/111584). Sorry but this is actually what can I help with. good luck

Comment: thanks, can you just say me where to execute this line ? I am not working from the shell and I have WIndows

Comment: It might be worth checking in the DB: has the layer been created? (if yes, change the 'create' option). If not, can the user create a table in the public schema? Do you have PostGIS enabled in this DB?

Comment: no it is not already created (even if I tried both). The user is me right ?  Yes I can create tables and postgis is enabled

Comment: It was so stupid ... I didn't enabled postgis in this DB but in another .. That xas the problem !! Thank you very much !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, that was quite a simple stupid error : I forgot to enable postgis in this specific Database, as JGH mentionned !

If you have the same problem, run "CREATE EXTENSION postgis", and everything should work !

Comment: Thank you, this was the solution for me too! Should it be `EXTENSION` instead of `EXTENTION`?